# exim4 forwarders are unrouteable for external mail but not internal

Tags: exim, mail-forwarding

I have exim4 configured to forward email for certain addresses.

The addresses are on virtual domains for which the server is the primary MX.

Other addresses on these domains are delivered to local mailboxes, but the addresses configured to forward go to external domains for which the server is not an MX and the mail should not be delivered to a local mailbox.

e.g. if the server is the primary MX for `example.com`, it should deliver mail locally for `user1@example.com` but `user2@example.com` should forward to `user2realname@gmail.com`.

All data for virtual domains and addresses is stored in MySQL.

The server OS is Debian.

The config for the forwarding router (in `/etc/exim4/conf.d/router/400_exim4-config_mysql_forward` is as follows:

```
mysql_forward:
  debug_print = "R: forwarder(mysql) for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = redirect
  no_verify
  no_expn
  check_ancestor
  forbid_smtp_code = true
  skip_syntax_errors
  domains = +local_domains
  data = ${lookup mysql{SELECT forward_to FROM mail_forwarders WHERE domain='${quote_mysql:$domain}' AND localpart='${quote_mysql:$local_part}' AND active=1} {${sg{$value}{\\n}{, }}}}
```

`exim -bt user2@example.com` outputs something like:

```
R: forwarder(mysql) for user2@example.com
R: dnslookup for user2realname@gmail.com
user2realname@gmail.com
    <-- user2@example.com
  router = dnslookup, transport = remote_smtp
  host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com      [74.125.133.27]  MX=5
  host alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [173.194.222.27] MX=10
  host alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [74.125.200.27]  MX=20
  host alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [74.125.23.27]   MX=30
  host alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [173.194.72.27]  MX=40
```

I can send mail with a local command and it is forwarded successfully.

However, when sending mail from an outside source, the mail is rejected with `550 Unrouteable address`, e.g.:

```
telnet mailserver.example.com 25
Connected to mailserver.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mailserver.example.com ESMTP
EHLO office.mylocaldomain.com
250-mailserver.example.com Hello office.mylocaldomain.com [21.22.23.24]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-PIPELINING
250 HELP
MAIL FROM: <user@mylocaldomain.com>
250 OK
RCPT TO: <user2@example.com>
550 Unrouteable address
QUIT
```

I'm sure more config will be required to diagnose this fully. Please ask and I will provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be the fault of `no_verify` in the router config. The docs recommend this setting for forwarders, but perhaps that is only appropriate when forwarding locally.